# Accessing a MySql DB via an IOS application

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode, web-services

looking for some advice on a couple of topics.

Im currently starting writing my first IOS application and have some questions.I wish to access some data from a mysql DB - this will hold hold a user table with logins and passwords, etc,...

1. Can i access the DB directly from IOS and perform my sql queries from within?
2. What is the standard way of encrypting a cached password for an application?
3. Is it best practice to perform all the queries from with the app or rely on a web server to proceess these and return the results?

Many thanks, apologies if a little vague but appreciate any constructive feedback guys.

thanks.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access db directly but this isn't ideal. Would be a better idea creating a rest api. Slim framework. Example below:

```
<?php
 $app = new \Slim\Slim();
  $app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
 echo "Hello, $name";
 });
 $app->run();
```

http://www.slimframework.com/

Would do the processing on the server and then just return a json object or xml you can then do what you want with the data.

Encrypting password you could store in keychain only your app will have access.

Comment: Thanks Tau.Ill look into the direct way first and then progress on the REST API work...many thanks !

Comment: Hi, The only reason why I think rest is a good idea is because if you publish the app and want to make a quick change. Rest will allow you to do that. If you do direct access then you will have to republish the app.

Comment: I agree. I did find an article that has a guide on how to develop one for starters. http://codewithchris.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app-mysql-wordpress/ ill give this a go and let you know how i get on! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
Can i access the DB directly from IOS and perform my sql queries from within?
reply : this is good pactice .
What is the standard way of encrypting a cached password for an application?
```

reply:  you can use many encrypting , has md5 ,etc 
    Is it best practice to perform all the queries from with the app or rely on a web server to proceess these and return the results?
   reply: yes you can use any webservice , json or xml it best for ios dev with webservice

Comment: Thanks Bipul. I notice your answer for Q1 contradicts Taus above. I have heard about using a rest API but would be interested in directly accessing the SQL tables. Ive done this before in Java but would be interested in more details on how I can perform the same via IOS. Do you have any more details on the classes used and any examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a database directly from the iOS using the MySQL C API. I haven't got this to work yet, but you can read more about it here: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/
and
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-function-overview.html

If you don't get it to work then you can indirectly connect to to MySQL via a PHP server. There are lots of these kind of tutorials out there.

Otherwise you could use SQLite that is bult in. But that's almost a different thing.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Please make sure your answer contains the important details of the solution.  Links should be used for supplemental information only.